# Other users play the games?

Tags: xbox-network

I purchased a used 360 and anytime I sign into a game or app on my profile while signed into xbox live, it immediately signs me out of xbox live, only to ask me to sign back in before it will let the app work. Netflix, youtube, anything. I have purchased a digital game. To access the game I have to be signed in to my account when I believe it should be available to all who are users, Correct? My daughter wants to play the game and has a profile on the machine but it will not allow her to access the game unless I am signed in. Then, when the console signs me out before the game loads, it demands that someone be signed in to save any progress. If I choose her profile, it will only allow her 9 minutes before demanding that the console reconnect to xbox live, which she does not have access to. It then terminates the game session because the console is not connected to xbox live. WTF?? I want to be able to sign into an app without the console immediately signing me out. I want my daughter to be able to play the game without being connected to xbox live. How do I do this?

Comment: Does her profile have xbox live silver (the free version) or no xbox live at all?

Comment: None at all. Does she have to have one?

Comment: Also, why would it keep signing me out everytime I select an app like Youtube or Netflix?